# C# ContextBoundObject error on windows 8.1

Tags: c#, .net, runtime-error, windows-8.1

When running this code on Windows 8.1 Preview:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BlaObject p = new BlaObject();
        }
    }

    public class BlaObject : ContextBoundObject
    {
        private readonly decimal decimalFactor = 10000;

        public BlaObject()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
AccessViolationException was unhandled
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

Any ideas? This code ran ok until today (I had 8.1 for about 3-4 days). It runs fine on windows 7 & 8.

Thanks.

Comment: did you try to cut the code down to the smallest code that exhibits this totally weird exception? (doing research about windows 8.1 issues before installing it, and am curious about your issue)

Comment: this is the smallest code that crashes. It seems it is a bug: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/796373/c-contextboundobject-error-on-windows-8-1